# Pagenavi and archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have some problems in making wp_pagenavi works. 
I have a custom post archive page in which I activated the function. Here's the code:

```
<?php 

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'connazionali' ),
    'nopaging'               => false,
    'paged'                  => '1',

);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ));
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

The pagination displays correctly but when I click on second page, the same three articles are displayed (even if the url /page/2 is correct).
I noticed this problem only on archive page, while on category page it is working fine.

Ho can I solve the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how wp_pagenavi() works, but can you try to set `paged` like this:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22Paged.22_Parameter_to_a_Query

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work... Any other idea?